# Что передается в адресную строку yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Использую `yii2`, в `view/index.php` добавил строку

```
<a href="<? echo Url::to(['Site/Delete', 'id' => $item['id']]) ?>" onclick="return confirm('Вы уверены?')" >Удалить</a>
```

В контроллере `SiteController` есть `actionDelete`.
Когда нажимаю навожу на ссылку, то показывает `index.php?r=Site/Delete&id=1`, но когда нажимаю на ссылку, то переходит по такой ссылке `index.php?r=Site%2FDelete&id=2` и показывает что страница не найдена.

Почему добавляются символы `%2F` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что у меня в config/web.php был закомментирован UrlManager